# Fabric SDK resource usage spike issue

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, performance-testing, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-js

We have containerized an express app using fabric node SDK to interact with the blockchain network.

We have deployed this alongside the fabric network on a single VM.

While testing with a certain load, we are observing that express app (fabric SDK) is consuming a lot of CPU and memory resources compared to other fabric components.

What I have observed is that, generating client object and channel object inside invoke-chaincode.js taking 50ms to 200ms collectively(fluctuating).

Could be this reason we have a spike in CPU and memory usage?

Machine Specification:

4 core, 8GB RAM, 256GB SSD

Network Spec:

Two ORG having two peers each, Two CA, one couch DB for each peer, solo orderer.